# AngularJS - ng-model value equals variable string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

sorry for a maybe confusing title.

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
    <input type="text" ng-model="{{input.name}}_{{input.year}}">
</div>
```

This does not work. This way the input field get bound to `{{input.name}}_{{input.year}}` instead of ex. `foo_2015`

My inputs list looks like this

```
$scope.inputs = [{name : foo, year : 2015},{name : bar, year : 2015}];
```

I have tried different answers i found on the net but can't find any that really answer my specific problem.

So how can i make this work?

Comment: And your question was?

Comment: Please be more specific. where should your variable `name_year` come from? Show us your controller so that we maybe will understand why you have something that looks quite strange

Comment: Try this. It may work `ng-model="this[input.name + '_'+ input.year]"`

Comment: @Chandermani if I try this it will return ng-model="this[input.name + '_'+ input.year]".

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

```
      $scope.inputs = [{ name: 'foo', year: 2015 }, { name: 'bar', year: 2015 }];
```

I think this will solve your problem if i understand your problem.

```
    <div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
        <input type="text" ng-model="input.name + '_'+ input.year"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ow sorry I already changed that in my code but appearantly forgot to change it here aswell. By just putting `"input.name + '_' + input.year"` it will be taken as a String so it will just show `ng-model="input.name + '_'+ input.year"` in the html

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted this answer but removed it afterwards so ill put it back since it worked for me:

```
<input type="text" ng-bind-model="{{input.name + '_' + input.year}}">
```

will become

```
<input type="text" ng-bind-model="foo_2015">
```

Answer (score 0):

If its only for displaying in html then use this

```
 <div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
    <input type="text" value="{{input.name}}_{{input.year}}">
</div>
```